# Rails cronjob problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cron, whenever

I've got a Rails 4 application with some cronjobs. I've migrated the app to a new debian server. At the moment I got this error from the Cronjobs.

```
stdin: is not a tty
```

a cronjob looks like that:

```
17,34,51 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /var/www/html/myapp && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake crons:mark_as_done --silent >> log/cron.log 2>&1'
```

wheres the problem? on my old machine I hadn't got this problem.

Thanks at all

cronjobs were set in scedule.rb and deployed with whenever

looks like this:

```
every 13.minutes do
  rake "crons:generate_m", :environment => :production
end
```

visudo
[image]

Result of cat /.bashrc
[image]

**UPDATE**

bashrc from working machine
[image]

Comment: Normally, this is because your sudoers file has a line `Defaults requiretty`. Just comment it out.

Comment: Where can I find this file?

Comment: As a root user, type `visudo`. Be very careful editing this file, since it is the one granting root privileges to non-root users.

Comment: can I edit this file with nano as well?

Comment: Sure, just say `EDITOR=/usr/bin/nano visudo`.

Comment: Checked that, but can't find the line you mentioned. Added the visudo above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is trying to read or operate on STDIN in a way that expects it to be a TTY.

If this doesn't happen on the other machine it is likely something in your rcfile (which is being loaded because you've indicated you want bash to act as a login shell with `-l`).

Check the `~/.bashrc` and comparable files on the new machine.

Comment: where do I find th rcfile?

Comment: The rcfile would be in the home directory of the user whose is running cron.  On that machine, if you run `cat ~/.bashrc` what is the output? If that file does not exist there may be other similarly named hidden files in the user's home directory. I assume you are logged in as the user who runs the cron job.

Comment: I've added the output of cat~/.bashrc above

Comment: added the working one as well. can I comment out the both alias ones?